# print a unicode NSString in reverse order

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have used this code to print an English `NSString` in reverse order:

```
     NSString *str = term;
    NSMutableArray *temp=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for(int i=0;i<[str length];i++)
    {
        [temp addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c",[str characterAtIndex:i]]];
    }
    temp = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[[temp reverseObjectEnumerator] allObjects]];
    NSString *reverseString=@"";
    for(int i=0;i<[temp count];i++)
    {
        reverseString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",reverseString,[temp objectAtIndex:i]];
    }
    NSLog(@"%@",reverseString);
```

but this code works only with English words, so when I try to use an Arabic word like this: تجريب  the console will show random English characters.

how can I use this code to print the reversed version of the above word (and any other similar Arabic (unicode) strings) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `%C` (uppercase C) instead of `%c` (lowercase c) format specifier in the first call to `stringWithFormat`. The lowercase 'c' format specifier is for 8-bit characters; the uppercase 'C' is for unicode.

**EDIT** : If you want to do it more efficiently, copy the data into an array of `unichar` elements, reverse the array, and feed the result into another `NSString`. This lets you reverse the string in `Length/2` steps:

```
NSString * s = @"تجريب";
unichar *cc = (unichar*)malloc(s.length+1);
[s getCharacters:cc];
for (NSUInteger i=0 ; i < s.length/2 ; i++) {
    // swap elements at i and s.length-i-1
    unichar tmp = cc[i];
    cc[i] = cc[s.length-i-1];
    cc[s.length-i-1] = tmp;
}
s = [NSString stringWithCharacters:cc length:s.length];
free(cc);
NSLog(@"%@", s);
```

Answer (score 2):

You have two for loops there and this code is very inefficient. I'd use `substringWithRange:` instead of `characterAtIndex:` and append it directly to the output string by iterating backwards through the string:

```
- (NSString *) createReverseStringFromString:(NSString *)inputString {
    if (inputString.length <= 0)
        return inputString;

    NSMutableString *mutableReverseString = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithCapacity:inputString.length];
    for (NSInteger i = inputString.length -1; i >= 0; i--) {
        NSString *characterString = [inputString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i, 1)];
        [mutableReverseString appendString:characterString];
    }

    NSString *outputString = [mutableReverseString copy];
    [mutableReverseString release];
    return [outputString autorelease];
}
```

You can then use this method like this:

```
NSString *inputString = @"تجريب";
NSString *outputString = [self createReverseStringFromString:inputString];
```

Answer (score 2):

A Cocoa way of doing it:

```
NSString *originalString = @"تجريب";

NSUInteger stringLength = originalString.length;

NSMutableString *reversedString = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithCapacity:stringLength];

while (stringLength) {
    [reversedString appendFormat:@"%C", [originalString characterAtIndex:--stringLength]];
}

NSLog(@"The reversed string is %@:", reversedString);
```

And this will work without leaking `reversedString` when compiled with ARC.